# How to deploy SSRS reports to Sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have experience deploying SSRS reports into sharepoint library by enabling the required content types. This was possible in sharepoint 2010-2016. Unfortunately I don't see the option to do the same in sharepoint online. Any help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint Online does not support SSRS. You can rebuild your reports for Power BI and embed PBI reports into SharePoint Online Modern pages using the Power BI webpart.